# Changing the order of events in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I created some pop-up code that will contain specific information from each link clicked in the pop-up. When closed, the content in the pop-up `div` gets deleted. Here is my code:

```
var $content = $('#popupcontent');
var $window = $('#popupwindow');
$('.open').click(function(){
    //alert('runnning');
    var a = $(this).contents('span');
    $content.append(a);
    $window.fadeIn(300);
});
$('.close').click(function(){
    //alert('running');
    var a = $content.contents('span');
    $window.fadeOut(300);
    $('#popupcontent span').remove();
});
```

My issue is that it is somehow removing the content before fading out, so the viewer can then see that the pop-up container goes blank. How can I make it so that it will surely fade out first and then remove the content? Here is a Jsfiddle to illustrate that: http://jsfiddle.net/kAdQK/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to utilize the complete call back argument for the fadeout method, to remove the element once `fadeout` is completed. With your current code it will start the fadeout animation and then immediately remove the content without waiting for fadeout animation to complete, hence you get the visual effect that you are seeing now. Using the callback you make sure that it gets executed once the animation is complete.

```
$window.fadeOut(300, function () {
        $('#popupcontent span').remove();
    });
```

[Syntax](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

> .fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete ] )

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8edqm/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the animation complete to remove your element after the fadeout ends.

The following code will ensure that `#popupcontent` is removed only after it's faded out

```
$window.fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#popupcontent span').remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a setTimeout();

```
$window.fadeOut(300);
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#popupcontent span').remove();},2000);
```

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/kAdQK/12/)

Comment: Is a `setTimeOut` necessary when you can achieve the same using a callback?

Comment: no, its not, but its always nice to know all the multiple ways of doing things

Comment: but again , if the OP wants to change the duration of `fadeOut` , won't he have to change the interval of the `timeout` . I am definitely not saying your code is wrong but was just pointing out the extra change which needs to be made.

Comment: True, true.....but unless he's making the fadeOut more than 4 seconds, which I doubt he is, this is a non-issue.....but you are right though :)

Comment: A second way of doing things,along with an example, does deserve a +1, :)